# create-react-app: Issue with first command using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-start

I want to create-react-app using npm. I try to follow this link https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

I Try to run "npx create-react-app my-app" command in my commond propmt , But it gives me error.
[image: Error message]

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'install',

1 verbose cli   '-g',

1 verbose cli   'create-react-app' ]

2 info using npm@6.4.1

3 info using node@v8.12.0

4 verbose npm-session 1bc5fca63b5e4cf5

5 silly install loadCurrentTree

6 silly install readGlobalPackageData

7 verbose stack TypeError: asyncWrite is not a function

7 verbose stack     at onwrite (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:480:
7)

7 verbose stack     at WritableState.onwrite (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:180:5)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream.to [as _worker] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:154:13)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream._write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:35:13)

7 verbose stack     at doWrite (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:428:64)

7 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:
417:5)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream.Writable.write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:334:11)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream.to [as _worker] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:
171:25)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream._write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:35:13)

7 verbose stack     at doWrite (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:428:64)

7 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:
417:5)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream.Writable.write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:334:11)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream.to [as _worker] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:182:19)

7 verbose stack     at WriteStream._write (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:35:13)

7 verbose stack     at doWrite (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:428:64)

7 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:417:5)

8 verbose cwd E:\xampp\htdocs

9 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134

10 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"

11 verbose node v8.12.0

12 verbose npm  v6.4.1

13 error asyncWrite is not a function

14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I also try to cache clean and also apply alternative way to run this command "npm install -g create-react-app" , but still not  solve my problem.

My node version is v8.12.0 and npm version is 6.4.1

Comment: Post your errors as text, not as an image.

Comment: @KalpeshPrajapati It is important to paste the error into a code block, as it makes life easier for people trying to help you, as well as making your question more searchable for anyone else sharing your problem. For more details, give [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) a read. Additionally, dismissing people like that who are trying to help you is not a good way to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running into [npx bug #100](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100) - there's a space in your directory name. Until that bug is fixed, the workaround is to do `npm cache clean` followed by `npm install -g create-react-app`. Then your original npx command should work.